# Whitelisting not working in Cordova 3.6.3 Android

Tags: android, cordova, whitelist

Due to a recent warning in the Google Store my Cordova app has to be upgraded to a version 3.5.1 or above. Therefore I created a new project with the CLI and tried to adapt the old app to the new structure as far as I could.

But now I have the problem that among other things my ajax server requests that try to fetch xml data get blocked with the message in Eclipse:

> W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(5095): URL blocked by whitelist:
>   http://www.myurl.com:1234/get/

I put my access tags in both *config.xml*, the one under platform/android and the one in the main project folder. It looks something like the following:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<!--     <access origin="*"/> -->
<access origin="http://123.456.789.000*"/>
<access origin="http://www.myurl.com*"/>
<access origin="http://*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Still since the version change the url still gets blocked. With the Cordova version from before all needed url's were accessible. Does someone have a solution for this?

Comment: have you tried removing `http://` from all of the access items (similar to the commented out line)?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Wildcard does work, but specific addresses don't, even without the http:// part. The cordova whitelist guide also includes it [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my mistake was pretty simple if anyone is interested. The "*" after the addresses are actually not relevant and older versions of cordova didn't have a problem with it.

Removing it solves the issue, I don't know why they were there anyway.